# Jquery - Only trigger blur event within a specific class

Tags: jquery

How can I set a limitation to an on blur trigger event. What I'm trying to do is call a function on blur of textarea, but the function shouldn't  be called if I click outside of the specified container.

**Edit**: It seems like there's no way to cancel the trigger event. In this case, how can I modify the function instead, so it will only return certain value on click within a specified container.

Code

```js
$('textarea').on('blur', function() {
  TestFunction();
});


function TestFunction() {
  // if clicked on container
  console.log('called')
  // else return
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green
}

.outside {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  Container
  <textarea>123</textarea>
</div>


<div class="outside">
 Outside
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't how the `blur` event works. It always fires regardless of the where the new focussed element is

Comment: `blur` can even be triggered by focusing out using keyboard's `tab` key. What do you expect in that case?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I updated my question.

Comment: I guess you could try checking which element has the focus in your event handler. If it's `div.container` or its child - then proceed with your blur handler.